# Socket Programming TCP . Server programming looping continuously

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

Following is the server.c program. When i connect a client to the server, the server starts looping infinitely in receive message part

**Server.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main()
{
    int sid,sid1,bin,lis,n,p,port, pid;
    struct sockaddr_in sin,c;
    socklen_t len;
    char buffer[40]="";
    char buffer1[20]="";
    char ip[30]="192.168.65.241";
    // printf("\nEnter the IP Address :");
    // scanf("%s",ip);
    printf("\nEnter the Port no.:");
    scanf("%d",&port);
    sid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);//END POINT CONN,
    if(sid<0)
    {
            perror("Socket : ");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nSocket created successfully...");
    sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port=htons(port);
    inet_aton(ip,&sin.sin_addr);//SERVER ADDRESS
    bin=bind(sid,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));//BIND ADDRESS WITH SOCKET
    if(bin<0)
    {
            perror("\nBind : ");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nBinding has been done successfully...");
    lis=listen(sid,10);//LISTEN TO THE CLIENT
    if(lis<0)
    {
            perror("\nListen : ");
            exit(0);
    }
    len=sizeof(c);

     while(1){

        printf("A Client is connected to the server.....");
        sid1=accept(sid,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,&len);//ACCEPT CONN.FROM CLIENT
        if(sid1<1)
        {
            perror("\nAccept : ");
            exit(0);
        }
        pid=fork();//CREATE PARENT AND CHILD PROCESS

        if(pid<0){

            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pid==0){

            lis=listen(sid,10);
            printf("\nEnter message...(Type END to terminate):\n");
            scanf("%s",buffer);
            while(strcmp(buffer,"END")!=0)
            {
                send(sid,buffer,30,0);//SEND TO SERVER
                scanf("%s",buffer);
            }
            send(sid,"END",5,0);
            printf("\nTerminating the server...\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else{

            n=recv(sid,buffer1,30,0);//RECEIVE FROM CLIENT
            buffer[n]='\0';
            n=strcmp(buffer1,"END");
            while(strcmp(buffer1,"END")!=0)
            {
                **printf("\nClient: %s\n",buffer1);** // Infinite Looping
                n=recv(sid,buffer1,30,0);
            }
            printf("\nA client has been disconnected from the server...\n");    
            exit(0);
        }
                            close(sid); //CLOSE CONNECTIONS
                                                                        close(sid1);    //CLOSE CONNECTIONS


     }
    shutdown(sid,2);    //SHUTDOWN READ AND WRITE
    close(sid); //CLOSE CONNECTIONS
}
```

**Client.c**

Client program isn't a problem.. Added the code for your reference.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{
    int sid,bi,con,n,p,port;
    char buffer[50],ip[30];
    sid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);//END POINT CONN.
    if(sid==-1)
    {
            perror("\nSocket :");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("A Socket created successfully....");
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    printf("\nEnter the IP Address :");
    scanf("%s",ip);
    printf("\nEnter the Port no. :");
    scanf("%d",&port);
    sin.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_aton(ip,&sin.sin_addr);
    con=connect(sid,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));//CONNECT TO SERVER
    if(con == -1)
    {
        perror("Connection : ");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nConnection is successfull to the server(%s)....\n",ip);
    p=fork();
    if(p)
        {
            printf("\nEnter message...(Type END to terminate):\n");
            scanf("%s",buffer);
            while(strcmp(buffer,"END")!=0)
            {
                    send(sid,buffer,30,0);//SEND TO THE SERVER
                    scanf("%s",buffer);
            }
            send(sid,"END",4,0);
        printf("\nTerminating the client...\n");
        exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                n=recv(sid,buffer,30,0);//RECV.FROM SERVER
        printf("%d",n);
        buffer[n+1]='\0';
            while(strcmp(buffer,"END")!=0)
            {
                    printf("\nServer: %s\n",buffer);
                    n=recv(sid,buffer,30,0);
            }
            send(sid,"END",4,0);
        exit(0);
        }
    printf("\nClient is terminated...\n");
    shutdown(sid,2);//SHUTDOWN READ AND WRITE
    close(sid); //CLOSE CONNECTIONS
}
```

Please let me know the Solution ASAP.

Comment: First start check for errors, there are some system calls which you don't check. For example in the child process, why are you calling `listen` on the server socket? That call will most likely fail.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, i.e. the infinite loop is simply because `recv()` is being called on the server's main socket (`sid`), not the socket returned by `accept()` - `sid1`. Change this:

```
n=recv(sid,buffer1,30,0);//RECEIVE FROM CLIENT
```

to

```
n=recv(sid1,buffer1,30,0);//RECEIVE FROM CLIENT
```

and

```
n=recv(sid,buffer1,30,0);
```

to

```
n=recv(sid1,buffer1,30,0);
```

and you will be in business.

There are other problems with the server code:

1. `recv()` is being told to read up to 30 bytes into `buffer1`,
   however, `buffer1` is only 20 bytes in size - you have a buffer
   overrun there.
2. If the client closes the connection without sending "END" and
   infinite loop will occur in the receive loop. You need to detect
   connection closure which is indicated by `recv()` returning 0.
3. `listen()` is being unnecessarily called in the server on line 64.

The above list is <strike>probably</strike> not exhaustive.

Comment: Infinite looping is stopped.. But Since i have written a multiple client accepting server, it doesnt happen so, Until i close the current client connect, it is ready to accept the next client... What is the solution for this ?

Comment: Actually, you seem to have it backwards. You are forking and handling the receipt of data in the _parent_, not the _child_. `fork()` returns 0 to the child and the process id of the child to the parent. In this case your receiving code calls `exit()` which terminates the parent. I have no idea what you are trying to do in the child code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong socket in the calls to read/write in `server.c`.

Right now, all calls to read/write fail, with `errno` indicating that the socket isn't connected.

You should use `sid1`, the connected socket, instead of `sid`.

You should also check the return values so you can detect and handle errors.